# deploy nodejs app on remote server with Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, axios

I am trying to deploy my on a remote server that's running Ubuntu. My application runs perfectly on my pc. now after deploying it online the frontend is showing this error when ever it is trying to call an api of the backend using axios, the error is:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:87)
```

I don't understand the problem, i already use CORS middle wear in my node backend. the frontend uses react and does the api call via axios, while the backend uses nodejs, and expressjs. any ideas?

Edit: thanks everyone problem solved.
In order for the call to work, I added the address to the nginx reverse proxy so it can be accessed from outside the server and then used this address with axios.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to still use the address of your computer (localhost). You have to replace that with the hostname or ip adress of the remote server.

Comment: thanks but when i curl http://localhost:8000/posts I get the data!!

Comment: Do you have a github repo I can look at? Too many variables to guess at without a working repo.

Comment: If you're curling localhost:8000/posts from your computer, then you are running the application also on your local machine. When you deploy it to a server, you need to access it via its own IP address. "localhost" is a loopback interface which just points at your own computer.

Comment: I'm curling it from inside the server. I'm SSH to the server then curl it from there. the frontend and the backend both are running on the server and they are local to each other

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED isn't the actual error generated by the server, it usually means that either the port isn't open or a hard block on connection request, are there any logs on the server for the request? (please share as it will greatly help solving the issue)

You wrote that it's working locally so I'll hazard a guess that your server is either missing or mismatching a npm module that causes your server to continously crash so the listen socket isn't open.

Comment: So the server is running since I can curl it. I'm even copying the address from my code and ssh it with a curl in the server and I'm getting the expected results

Comment: Ok so now I put this like into the nginx reverse proxy and when I call it from the browser I get: cannot GET /w